# AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have table mm with field id,name and sal

I inserted encrypted value in the DB using the AES_ENCRYPT

```
psmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into mm values("+id+",AES_ENCRYPT('"+name+"','"+key+"'),AES_ENCRYPT('"+sal+"','"+key+"'))");
```

It is working properly

but when i am trying to retrieve these values using AES_DECRYPT

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select id,AES_DECRYPT(name,'"+key+"'),AES_DECRYPT(sal,'"+key+"') FROM mm WHERE id="+rs.getInt(1)+"");
```

When i am applying query on mysql console it work properly.

but when apply using java code it gives values like

```
| 1| [B@1f0690a| [B@803365 |
```

Why i am getting these values instead of the original values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `toString()` on a byte-array does not return the content of the byte array, but `[B@` followed by the identity hashcode of the byte array. In your insert you did not use the content of `key` as the key, but the `toString`-value. You need to use a `PreparedStatement` with a parametrized query, and set the values using `setBytes`:

```
psmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into mm values (?, AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?), AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?))");
psmt.setInt(1, id);
psmt.setString(2, name);
psmt.setBytes(3, key);
psmt.setstring(4, sal);
psmt.setBytes(5, key);
```

And do the same for your select query.

You should never concatenate values into your query. It will make you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Change your process sequence.

First, just select your value from table.

```
From your eg. --> | 1| [B@1f0690a| [B@803365 |
```

Second, decrypt these two column using AES_DECRYPT.

Comment: But the AES_DECRYPT works only on mysql console how can i decrypt in java

Comment: If so, I agree with @Mark Rotteveel answer by using psmt with params query!!