# AES_ENCRYPT with mysql server 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, jdbc

I am trying to insert data in to MySQL in encrypted format using prepared statement. But I am getting this error. I think my query is correct.

```
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement psmt1=null;

    String tit=request.getParameter("tit");
    String min=request.getParameter("minvalue");
    String max=request.getParameter("maxvalue");
   String disc=request.getParameter("disc");
    System.out.println(tit);
    String [] title=tit.split(":");

   try{
   con=databasecon.getconnection();
  psmt1=con.prepareStatement("insert into medication(tid,titname,minvalue,maxvalue,disc) values(AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'))");

psmt1.setString(1,title[0]);
psmt1.setString(2,title[1]);
psmt1.setString(3,min);
psmt1.setString(4,max);
psmt1.setString(5,disc);
psmt1.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
out.println("Error in connection : "+ex);
}
```

Below is my connection class

```
package databaseconnection;
import java.sql.*;

public class databasecon
{
    static Connection con;
    public static Connection getconnection()
    {


        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cam","root","root");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("class error");
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

And finally error is

```
Error in connection : java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue,disc) values(AES_ENCRYPT('6', 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT('systolic bp', 'key'),' at line 1
```

As requested by my fellow developer i am posting my table sturuture
[image: Below is my table def:]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AES\_ENCRYPT and AES\_DECRYPT using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938636/aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is the case, but you need to pass in a byte array as the second parameter to MySQL's [AES_ENCRYPT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt):

```
psmt1 = con.prepareStatement("insert into medication(tid,titname,minvalue,maxvalue,disc) values(AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'key'))");

byte[] keyBytes = "key".getBytes();
psmt1.setString(1, title[0]);
psmt1.setBytes(2, keyBytes);
psmt1.setString(3, title[1]);
psmt1.setBytes(4, keyBytes);
psmt1.setString(5, min);
psmt1.setBytes(6, keyBytes);
psmt1.setString(7, max);
psmt1.setBytes(8, keyBytes);
psmt1.setString(9, disc);
psmt1.setBytes(10, keyBytes);
psmt1.executeUpdate();
```

I say that I don't have an explanation because the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) implies that both parameters to `AES_ENCRYPT` are strings.  I would have made this mistake myself.

Comment: no that didn't solved my problem i am getting following error

Comment: Even I tried inserting with out encryption also but i failed psmt1=con.prepareStatement("insert into  medication(tid,titname,minvalue,maxvalue,disc) values(?,?,?,?,?))");

Comment: Post your table definition.

Comment: please verify i posted

Comment: What exact error do you get when you run my answer?